Efficiently compute the diagonal of the inverse of a sparse matrix
In Python have a large NxN sparse matrix representing the precision matrix Q (inverse covariance matrix) of a multivariate Gaussian distribution. I am interested in obtaining the marginal variances of the model. These will be the elements on the diagonal of the inverse precision matrix (the diagonal elements of the covariance matrix).
As Q is very large I must avoid inverting the full matrix. Solving a linear system to obtain the result is also not fast enough. However it is a known result that the diagonal elements can be computed efficiently using the sparse Cholesky factorization. This is described in Equation 12.23 in the book "Handbook of Spatial Statistics" by Gelfand (2010). The book "Gaussian Markov Random Fields" by Rue and Held (2005) also contains some information regarding this.
In R the function inla.qinv from the R-INLA library does exactly what I am looking for. How can I obtain a similar functionality as the inla.qinv function in Python? Alternatively are there any other ways I can efficiently calculate or estimate the diagonal elements?
As of now i use the sksparse.cholmod package for sparse Cholesky decomposition, but are open to other methods. Simply solving the inverse problem by
import scipy.sparse as sparse
from sksparse.cholmod import cholesky
inverse_diagonal = cholesky(Q).solve_A(sparse.eye_array(Q.shape[0])).diagonal()

is not fast enough for my need.
One alternative is to use the rpy2 package in Python to run R-functions. However, this is a complication I want to avoid. Additionally, from testing I have found that simply running the qinv function using rpy2 does not work as intended.
If there are any C-libraries that does the desired computation this can certainly be a possibility! qinv uses the C-library GMRFLib under the hood, so maybe this could be worth trying?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

By the way, exactly how large is the matrix in question?

@RobertDodier The matrix will vary in size based on the particular problem. However, as a "baseline" I am usually looking at matrices with size around N=10000.
